# How does Python or Javascript manage resizing arrays?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, performance, memory

How do either of these languages manage resizing an array?
So, say I create an array with 10 indexes, and then I need to add an element. In java, I would double the size of the array and keep adding. In languages like JS and Python, what mechanisms do they use to resize the array?

Do they also double the size of the array in memory?

Comment: Under what circumstances? Which implementation(s)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe clarified the question

Comment: There are many implementations of both languages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software#Python_implementations) - each is free to handle these cases as the developers felt was best. I believe the reference CPython implementation doubles the size of the underlying array if a list gets (two thirds? Or is that just dicts) full. But note that both are high level languages where you are simply encouraged *not to worry about it!*

Comment: a js array doesn't need to be an actual array in the machine.

Comment: An array in JavaScript or Python is more similar to Java's List or ArrayList than its fixed-length arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It is an implementation detail, there is no guarantee that it will be done in any particular way.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code for CPython is [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l42):

```
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);

/* check for integer overflow */
if (new_allocated > PY_SIZE_MAX - newsize) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    return -1;
} else {
    new_allocated += newsize;
}
```

So no, it does not double the size. If an append/extend is going to cause the length of the list to be `newsize`, the allocated memory of the backing array grows to about that plus an eighth.

For [Java OpenJDK 7 ArrayLists](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l204):

```
/**
 * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
 * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
 *
 * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
 */
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

So an extra half of the required capacity.

Please use an `ArrayList` rather than managing your own resizing array.

Answer (score 0):

In Python and Javascript, you just don't have to worry about it. In neither of the languages do you even need to declare the size of the List/Array. Feel free to add or remove elements without considering this.

I don't understand the concern with such finite memory usage when you're programming with these high-level languages. If you're writing in Javascript, your code is probably being interpreted and ran on an Intel I5 with 4+GB RAM. You're probably OK.